# mysql Performance problem on query with group by

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i have a performance problem. I have a table called Alarmes with 20 columns. In this table i am only interested in 2 columns(ALM_TAGNAME and ALM_LOGNODENAME). The table is created and updated automatically from another program, i only want to make a statistic.
Well, i added a key on the two columns ALM_TAGNAME and also on ALM_LOGNODENAME, but even with this keys the select uses over 40 seconds to execute. I just reduced the amount of lines but it is still over 1 million lines.

```
SELECT ALM_TAGNAME as 'tag', count(*) as  'cnt'    FROM Alarmes WHERE ALM_LOGNODENAME='plantid' GROUP BY ALM_TAGNAME;
```

> CREATE TABLE `Alarmes` (
>   `ALM_NATIVETIMEIN` datetime NOT NULL, 
>   `ALM_NATIVETIMELAST` datetime default
>   NULL,   `ALM_LOGNODENAME` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_PHYSLNODE` varchar(50) character
>   set utf8 default NULL,   `ALM_TAGNAME`
>   varchar(50) character set utf8 default
>   NULL,   `ALM_TAGDESC` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_VALUE` varchar(50) character set
>   utf8 default NULL,   `ALM_UNIT`
>   varchar(50) character set utf8 default
>   NULL,   `ALM_MSGTYPE` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_DESCR` varchar(255) character set
>   utf8 default NULL,   `ALM_ALMSTATUS`
>   varchar(50) character set utf8 default
>   NULL,   `ALM_ALMPRIORITY` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_ALMAREA` varchar(50) character
>   set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_ALMEXTFLD1` varchar(50) character
>   set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_ALMEXTFLD2` varchar(50) character
>   set utf8 default NULL,   `ALM_OPNAME`
>   varchar(50) character set utf8 default
>   NULL,   `ALM_OPFULLNAME` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_OPNODE` varchar(50) character set
>   utf8 default NULL,   `ALM_PERFNAME`
>   varchar(50) character set utf8 default
>   NULL,   `ALM_PERFFULLNAME` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_PERFBYCOMMENT` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_VERNAME` varchar(50) character
>   set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_VERFULLNAME` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_VERBYCOMMENT` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_DATEIN` varchar(50) character set
>   utf8 default NULL,   `ALM_TIMEIN`
>   varchar(50) character set utf8 default
>   NULL,   `ALM_DATELAST` varchar(50)
>   character set utf8 default NULL,
>   `ALM_TIMELAST` varchar(50) character
>   set utf8 default NULL,   KEY
>   `Alarmes_tagname` (`ALM_TAGNAME`),
>   KEY `Alarmes_lognodname`
>   (`ALM_LOGNODENAME`) )

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ALM_TAGNAME as 'tag', count(ALM_TAGNAME) as  'cnt'    FROM monitor.Alarmes   WHERE ALM_LOGNODENAME='bogota'   GROUP BY ALM_TAGNAME;    +----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Alarmes | ref  | Alarmes_lognodname | Alarmes_lognodname | 153     | const | 86143 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+

 DESCRIBE SELECT ALM_TAGNAME as 'tag', count(ALM_TAGNAME) as  'cnt'    FROM monitor.Alarmes   WHERE ALM_LOGNODENAME='bogota'   GROUP BY ALM_TAGNAME;
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Alarmes | ref  | Alarmes_lognodname | Alarmes_lognodname | 153     | const | 86154 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps try rebuilding the indexes? Also, if it is for statistics gathering, I would cache the results in an aggregate table.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Well, i added a key on the two columns ALM_TAGNAME and also on ALM_LOGNODENAME", do you add an **INDEX** on ALM_TAGNAME+ALM_LOGNODENAME or two indexes ?

If you add ALM_TAGNAME+ALM_LOGNODENAME, try to add just one **index** on ALM_TAGNAME.

Answer (score 0):

How frequent is the data changing where you need the COUNT(*)s..., have you considered a nightly (or even hourly) pre-aggregated table to get your query / counts from THAT table..  Then, your query against THAT table on your tag name / log node name would be a single record and done..